# How to read RabbitMQ queue messages one by one

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have a requirement where I need to read the messages of DLQ and do appropriate action based on that. Earlier, below code snippet was working fine before the RabbitMQ/Erlang update. Now it gives Bad Request error.

```py
import urllib2
import json
import optparse

class http_worker:

    def authentication(self, url, user, pw):
        password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm() 
        password_manager.add_password(None, url, user, pw)

        self.auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager) 
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(self.auth) 
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    def call_url(self, url, body_raw):
        body = json.dumps(body_raw)
        #
        # urllib2 post since there is body 
        #
        req = urllib2.Request(url, body, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        return urllib2.urlopen(req)

user = "guest"
pwd = "guest"
rabbit_host = "http://localhost:15672"
host_suffix = "/api/queues/%%2F/%s/get" %(rabbit_queue_name)

url = rabbit_host + host_suffix
body_raw = {"count":5000,"requeue":True,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}

worker = http_worker()
worker.authentication(url, user, pwd)
res = worker.call_url(url, body_raw)
result = json.loads(res.read())
...
```

So, I tried to change this and used new libraries of Python like urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse, and requests. But issue persists.

Is it because latest version of RabbitMQ stopped accepting this kind of REST call? 
What could be alternative to read all messages one by one in Python for performing required action?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We introduced a breaking change here:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/pull/199

The body raw is:

```
body_raw = 
{"count":5000,"ackmode":"ack_requeue_false",
"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}
```

There are 4 choises, instead of a boolean:

```
ackmode=ack_requeue_false
ackmode=ack_requeue_true
ackmode=reject_requeue_false
ackmode=reject_requeue_true
```

please read [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/68) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for help. It allows to get message. Now I am stuck on next level.

Comment: After receiving results, I want to concatenate all values of key-properties. Here it works perfectly if I run from MS DOS command prompt, Visual Studio Code. When I run the same from  Bash Ubuntu it throws me error while calling print_out method.  The error is " the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'".

Comment: print_out code block is as:


```python
msg = urllib.request.urlopen(req, requestJsonBytes)
print_out(json.loads(res.read()))


def print_out(my_json):
    print("Inside print_out method")
    for item in my_json:
        print("inside the loop and printing current item:")
        out = []
        for _, val in sorted(item.get("properties").get("headers").items()):
            print(str(val))
            out.append(str(val))
        print(", ".join(out))
```

Comment: You really should start a new question, and provide complete details on how to reproduce. Finally, you should *not* be using the HTTP API to retrieve messages - why aren't you using a library like Pika?

Comment: @LukeBakken agree, I am creating a new question thread. Yes, I tried Pika but unable to retrieve all messages in one shot.

Comment: You shouldn't try to retrieve messages all at once. You're not using RabbitMQ correctly if that is your goal.

Comment: @LukeBakken actually my interest is in fileName and filePath properties of dead-queue messages. You are right, it would be really good if I go one by one and read only these properties anyhow. I tried reading single message using Pika though still clueless for properties specific reads.